# Block website rooted phone

Tags: root-access

Help please!

I have a rooted samsung s6.
Im wondering how I can block certain websites.
I dont understand if supersu or titanium backup pro can be used. What should I download to bl8ck websites?

Comment: You can try searching for the solution as the very first step with keywords as simple as "block websites". See https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=block+websites On a rooted phone, a hosts file based solution is the easiest. Add sites in the hosts file (Magisk does this systemless-ly), reboot, profit!

Comment: Thank you for your reply firelord! What kind of host files solutions do you mean? Should I download Magisk?

Comment: Just edit the system hosts file and add an entry per DNS name that redirects those domains you want to block to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you Robert! How do I edit the system hosts file? Do I do that in Supersu or in titanium backup?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+edit+hosts+file

Comment: you can use any app like [AdAway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de2X3.png) for edit hosts